# Localize tinymce in WordPress 3.9?

Tags: tinymce, translation

Still stucked with this localization of tinymce. Find this resource here : [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_languages). Does not seem to work anymore.

How do you do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is there something you ultimately want to achieve?

Comment: in fact the codex totally works, I missed I use a reserved term which is pretty bad :/